# Add per-page selector to Django admin list-view

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-admin

I would like to add a per-page selector in the list-view of ModelAdmin.

Like this: 
[image]

I could not find anything specific to this in django admin docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

I've also tried `list_per_page` attribute.

I'm using Django 1.7.7.

Am I missing something from docs, or is there any 3rd party app available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to customize djnago admin. Use jQuery to solve purpose.
Use Jquery and hit a service with page=20 or page=50 and in view.py get records according ot passing param.